# If I have a mass on a spring does it change it's rest length?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy, spring

If, for example, I have a mass on a spring that compresses it of a length x. If I compress the spring more of a length y, when I release the spring the kinetic energy of the mass would be $\frac12 ky^2$ or $\frac12 k(x+y)^2$? And the mass will be released at height $x+y, x$ or $0$?

Comment: Hi. What do **you** think?

Comment: You should go through the problem step-by-step rather than try to get the final answer in a single thought.  You'll remember it much better if you do the steps yourself.

Comment: Hi TheNewHEROBRINE! Welcome to Physics SE :) When you _release_ a mass, its kinetic energy is, by definition, zero. What do you mean when you say "when I release the spring, the kinetic energy of the mass would be $\frac{1}{2}ky^2$ or $\frac{1}{2}k(x+y)^2$"?

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear, I meant the kinetic energy that the mass will gain when the potential energy of the spring is converted into kinetic energy because of the spring returning in its equilibrium position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The force on the mass will be the sum of the gravitational force $-mg$ and the spring force $kx$.  Since the net force is initially zero this means $kx =mg$.  If you stretch an additional distance $y$ the force is $F = k(x+y) - mg$.  However, since $kx = mg$ you can just write this as $F = ky$.  The problem becomes identical to a spring compressed a distance $y$, and you can ignore $x$.  Thus, the mass will oscillate between $h = x-y$ and $ h = x+y$ and have a maximum kinetic energy $K=\frac{1}{2}ky^2$ at height $h = x$.

Comment: Hi Laurence! Welcome to Physics SE. :) The OP also asked about where the mass would be released which I understand to mean as to where the mass will leave the spring if it is not "glued" to it.

Comment: I don't understand what is being asked by the "where the mass would be released" part of the question.

Comment: As far as I understand (partly based on an idea of what such questions usually want to mean), I think it means to ask that if the mass is not glued to the spring but is free to fly-off at a certain point during its motion, at what point does the mass fly-off.

Comment: Spring kinetic energy ? There is nothing like this

Comment: Didn't mean to imply the spring had the kinetic energy.  Thanks for the comment.  Tried to edit this to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

When you put the mass on the spring, it will have a potential energy

$$\frac{1}{2}kx^2$$

this is now it's new equilibrium position.

When you push it further it will increase it's potential energy to

$$\frac{1}{2}k(x^2+y^2)$$

Now, if the mass is attached and assuming kinetic energy is lost after dampened oscillations, the spring will come to rest to it's equilibrium position with the mass, that is, compressed $x$ length.

If the mass were not attached and could go flying off, the spring will return to it's original form after releasing it (assuming it didn't get deformed by the mass).

Comment: Why is it 1/2k(x^2 + y^2) and not 1/2k(x + y)^2?

Comment: @LucaBiazzetti You are correct. The spring system PE will be $1/2 k (x+y)^2$. There will also be a decrease in the gravitational PE of the system of |mgy|.

Answer (score 0):

The spring potential energy is:

$$U=\frac{1}{2}\,k\,(x+y)^2$$

Why ?

lets look at the equation of motion:

with:

$$L=\frac{1}{2}\,m\,\dot{y}^2+\frac{1}{2}\,k\,(x+y)^2-m\,g\,y$$

you get:

$$m\,\ddot{y}+k\,(x+y)=m\,g$$

thus the equilibrium at t=0 ($\quad y(0)=0\,,\dot{y}(0)=0\quad$) is: $$x=\frac{m\,g}{k}$$

Comment: How does this answer any of the two questions asked by the OP?

Comment: @Dvij This is the control that the ansatz for the spring potential energy is correct,
otherwise you don't get the static equilibrium for x ?
if you make the ansatz $U=\frac{1}{2}\,k\,y^2$ you don't get the static equilibrium .

Comment: Yes, I understand but the OP is asking about the kinetic energy of the mass (it is unclear at what point during the motion the OP wants to evaluate this kinetic energy--but seems like they are interested in the maximum kinetic energy attained by the mass during its entire course of motion) and about the configuration in which the mass flies off. The OP never asked about the potential energy of the spring.